# regex match optional part

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that shows how much time is left:

```
text = """                9d 15h left <br />
                           some other text not important
                           12h 5m left <br />""" 
pattern = "((\d+)d)?.*left <br />"
```

I'd like to match the number of days, or 9. However, if that's missing, I'd like to match an empty string. This is what I get

```
>>> re.findall(pattern,text)
[('', ''),('', '')]
```

But what I'm looking for is

```
>>> re.findall(pattern,text)
[('9d', '9'),('', '')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the spaces in the pattern:

either:

```
re.search(r"[ ]+((\d+)d)?.*left <br />", text).groups()
```

or strip the text before

```
re.search(r"((\d+)d)?.*left <br />", text.strip()).groups()
```